# Using javascript "GroupImage.src=GroupDB[i].picture" adds "%26/#47"

Tags: javascript, image, addition

I'm trying to add an image to a 'div' dynamically generated. For that I use:

```
GroupImage = document.createElement("img");
            GroupImage.src=GroupDB[i].picture;

CurrentGroup.appendChild(GroupImage);
```

CurrentGroup is a div and "GroupDB[i].picture" contains an URL. In this case the URL is: https://lh4.googleusercontent.com/-ugAXmjWxPm0/UNfk2VwTa6I/AAAAAAAAGpE/88dMKe8VaeI/s144/376290009_1ddbf70515_b.jpg
 which points to a picture but when using it with GroupImage.src=GroupDB[i].picture I get the URL plus '%26/#47'

but when I use "GroupImage.src=GroupDB[i].picture" what I get is <'img src="https:&#47/lh4.googleusercontent.com/-ugAXmjWxPm0/UNfk2VwTa6I/AAAAAAAAGpE/88dMKe8VaeI/s144/376290009_1ddbf70515_b.jpg'> which adds the "%26/#47" portion and does not open the link. Can anyone help me unsertand what happens?

Thanks!

Comment: Can you show how GroupDB is created / filled with urls?

Comment: GroupDB comes from a $getJSON("url", function(){}) where the url is a google spreadsheet. If I do console.log(GroupDB.picture); I read the correct URL in the browser console. It's when passing this URL using GroupImage.src when the extra characters get added.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As you can see here (http://jsfiddle.net/q4vEu/), it's working..

```
var CurrentGroup = document.getElementById('currentgroup');
var GroupDB = [{
    picture: "https://lh4.googleusercontent.com/-ugAXmjWxPm0/UNfk2VwTa6I/AAAAAAAAGpE/88dMKe8VaeI/s144/376290009_1ddbf70515_b.jpg"
}];
var GroupImage = document.createElement('img');
GroupImage.src = GroupDB[0].picture;
CurrentGroup.appendChild(GroupImage);
```

The image is successfully loaded.

Comment: Oh you know. Sorry, I found my error. I have a function between the getJSON and the time I pass the information to the the CurrentGroup div where I 'sanitize' the input (It can be changed by external users) and that's what is causing the problem. Thanks a lot for pointing me to the root cause!